# Authentication using social-auth library in grails for facebook,google,twitter

Tags: grails, socialauth

I am following the example given in link https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithGrails but everytime it authenticates using google,its getting redirected to error page.I tried with localhost and also with domain they are providing in example.Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the latest Grails demo from [SocialAuth 4.2 SDK](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/downloads/detail?name=socialauth-java-sdk-4.2.zip&can=2&q=) 
If it doesn't work then you can POST issue on https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/issues/list